# Is there a way to change "all" Java related "File and Code" Templates in ONE place?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-templates

By convention, our java files need our company copyright header as first entry in the file.

With IntelliJ, you can turn to 
*Preferences->File and Code Templates*, and then, in the *Includes* tab, there is an entry "File Header" where you can drop such copyright information. All fine.

But: in the "Files" list that defines the various applicable "types", each type has its own "rule", like:

[image: screen-shot-class]

As you can see, that "rule" puts the package name first, so I have to go and change that rule to:

```
#parse("File Header.java")
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
public class ${NAME} {
}
```

But, as said: there are multiple "types" that need the very same setup (Class, Interface, Enum, Annotation).

Is there a way to have all Java-related "types" use the same rule, **without** me going in and updating each entry manually, individually?

Comment: I guess no. You would have finished updating each entry if you hadn't asked it :) There are not so many templates there...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I did finish doing that in the meantime. But not asking for me, but for the good of all Kree. Err, sorry, for the good of all future readers.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to edit all the templates at once.