# Why does IntelliJ put comment headers in the wrong place ... for tests only?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have slightly modified the default *File and Code Template* for Java "Class" (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57375531/is-there-a-way-to-change-all-java-related-file-and-code-templates-in-one-pla) for context):

```
#parse("File Header.java")
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
public class ${NAME} {
}
```

and the Java "File header" entry (in the "Includes" tab) I defined a copyright header.

When I now do a new (production) class, IntelliJ creates:

```
/* that copyright header */    
package com.foo.bar

public class Whatever { ...
```

Fine. When I then go "create me a unit test", what gets created is:

```
package com.foo.bar
/* that copyright header */    

public class WhateverTest { ...
```

Is this a bug? Or how can this be fixed?

Comment: Aren't class comments supposed to be above class? I think it puts it below because import statements get folded anyways.

Comment: @Goion The point is that you usually want such copyright headers to show up **once**, on top of each file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug, simply a feature, based on the fact that IntelliJ allows you to define these "File and Code templates" in **multiple** places/tabs!

The "Files" tab shows entries for Class, Interface, ...

[image: files-tab]

But note that there is also that **Code** tab. And there you find entries such as **JUnit 4 Test class**:

[image: code-tab]

Thus the (simple) solution: understand that JUnit classes have their distinct format spec, which show up in a different place! Just adapt things there accordingly, and everything works as expected.

Finally: the "definition" then needs to be updated to mathc the Java class one, like:

[image: junit-class]

Textual:

```
#parse("File Header.java")
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class ${NAME} {
  ${BODY}
}
```